# Creating a multi-dimensional hashtable with generics in VB ASP.NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics, asp.net-2.0

I need to create a multi-dimensional (nested) hashtable/dictionary so that I can use syntax like

```
val = myHash("Key").("key")
```

I know I need to use Generics but I can't figure out the correct syntax using VB in ASP.NET 2.0, there are plenty of c# examples on the net but they aren't helping much.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm better at C# than vb.net, but I'll give this a go....

```
Dim myHash as Dictionary(Of string, Dictionary(Of string, Integer));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Dictionary type in VB.NET as far as I can see.  IntelliSense doesnt like that snippet and wants to change it to ListDictionary or HybridDictionary, both of which then give the error message: "... has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments"

Comment: Umm, MSDN says it exists.  Are you including the right Imports statement for System.Collections.Generic?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Doh!  I'd imported Specialized not Generic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's also the System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary(Of T) collection, which is just a pre-defined Dictionary(Of String, T).

And the syntax to use either the normal Dictionary or the StringDictionary would look like this:

```
val = myHash("key")("key")
```

Not like this:

```
val = myHash("key").("key")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you may only need  to use Dictionary, and that can compose your multiple keys into a single key object with its own composite hash code. E.g. make a multikey class and then use it as the key.

in pseudocode:

```
class Multikey {
 private keys;
 public setKey1(...)
 public setKey2(...)
}
Dim myKey as MultiKey(...)
myKey.key1 = ...
myKey.key2 = ...

Dim mydic as Dictionary(Of MultiKey, Integer)

val = mydic(myKey)
```

Comment: He's lose his sytnactic sugar, though.

Comment: You're right. But then again there is: 

val = dic.get(new MultiKey("key1").("key2"))

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you'd never be able to get it out.  You can make a new key object from the same values, but it wouldn't point to the same object in the dictionary because it's a different object.